# How to stub using any_instance in Rspec feature spec with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have the following in a feature spec:

```
it "shows the page" do
    Project.any_instance.stub(:price_all)
    login_user
    gso = create(:gs_option)
    gso.gs_collector.collector.project.update(user_id: @user.id)
    visit edit_gs_option_path(gso)
  end
```

Yet, it always fails because the price_all method on Project is not being stubbed.  The failure trace contains the following:

```
 # ./app/models/project.rb:430:in `price_all'
```

How do I stub the price_all method on the Project class?

I've tried `stub(:price_all).with(anything())` and `stub(:price_all).with(any_args())`, but it doesn't change the failure message.

Here's the full failure:

```
 1) GS Options page shows the page
 Failure/Error: visit edit_gs_option_path(gso)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/collector.rb:435:in `price_item'
 # ./app/models/gs_collector.rb:279:in `price_out'
 # ./app/models/collector.rb:260:in `price_out_all'
 # ./app/models/project.rb:430:in `price_all'
 # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:187:in `get_totals'
 # ./app/controllers/gs_options_controller.rb:6:in `edit'
 # ./spec/features/gs_options_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: can we see the full error?

Comment: and what line is `/spec/features/gs_options_spec.rb:10`?

Comment: It's the `visit edit_gs_option_path(gs)` line.

Comment: is `price_all` a class method by any chance? If so, you don't want to stub it out on any ___instance___ of Project.

Comment: It's not a class method.  But rspec's any_instance method is supposed to take care of stubbing all instances....

Comment: can we see some of the related code to verify?

Comment: Which code?  To verify what?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the little bit of code here but since this looks like a feature spec, if you are using capybara and using anything other than RackTest, then there are two separate processes and your stub will not be in effect in the other process. Going a step further, if this is a feature/integration/acceptance test with Capybara, you should not be stubbing anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Capybara.  The original question mentions it is a feature spec.  Any workaround for the two separate processes issue?

Comment: The only thing you should be stubbing out in a feature spec is any interaction with external APIs.

Comment: Can't agree with that.  Stubbing can be used to test javascript functionality, which is one of the things I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

This stubbing feature started working when I upgraded to rspec-rails 3.0.0.beta.